# How do you authenticate JsonApiClient with a JWT BearerToken?

Tags: servicestack

I'm using `IClientAccessTokenManagementService` from [Identity Model](https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aspnetcore/web.html) to obtain a JWT token that will authorize my client.

I'm setting Bearer Token, but keep getting 403 Unauthorized. I wish I could use `CaptureHttp` but that isn't available with the JsonApiClient

[ServiceStack docs](https://docs.servicestack.net/csharp-client#jsonapiclient) say to use `JsonApiClient`, but then shows all the docs using `JsonServiceClient`.

```cs
// JsonServiceClient works
var jsc = new JsonServiceClient(myCompanyApi);
jsc.CaptureHttp(log: true); // function not available with JsonApiClient
jsc.BearerToken = myClientAccessToken;
var jscResults = jsc.Get(request);

// JsonApiClient returns Failed and Unauthorized
// _jsonApiClient instance is from named HttpClient in the Factory 
_jsonApiClient.BearerToken = myClientAccessToken;
var apiResults = _jsonApiClient.Api(request);
```

**clarifying update**

If I set the bearer token directly on the underly http client then the JsonApiClient is successful

`_jsonApiClient.HttpClient.SetBearerToken(myClientAccessToken);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your BearerToken needs to be set when initializing the `JsonApiClient`, e.g:

```cs
var client = new JsonApiClient(myCompanyApi) {
    BearerToken = myClientAccessToken,
};
```

Which will be populated on the underlying `HttpClient` instance that gets constructed when sending the first request.

To populate it after requests have been made you'll need to set it on the underlying `HttpClient`, e.g:

```cs
client.GetHttpClient().DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = 
    new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", myClientAccessToken)
```

Comment: Can you confirm using the JsonApiClient ctor with an HTTPClient, means you need to explicitly set the authorization header on the underlying Http Client like?

In practice that seems true.

Comment: Right if the HttpClient is already initialized, JsonApiClient wont construct it with the configured Headers, so it would need to be explicitly set.